# Error: uninitialized constant Fiddle::VERSION

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rubygems

I am getting the following error while trying to run rails console **"Error: uninitialized constant Fiddle::VERSION"**

I am using Rails 5.2.5 and mongo db for database.
I am not sure what the error is.
Please help me out to resolve this issue

Comment: Which version of Ruby du you use?

Comment: I am using ruby 2.6.5p114

Comment: Fiddle::VERSION included in Ruby 3.0.1 and above.  For example, 2.7.3 not include: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.3/libdoc/fiddle/rdoc/Fiddle.html. But 3.0.1 include: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/fiddle/rdoc/Fiddle.html. So, you would to upgrade your Ruby to 3.0.1 before.